# How browser find IP address from domain name?

Tags: browser, web-applications, dns, web

As we enter url in browser. browser check IP address in host file for domain name. And If IP address is not find in there than how browser find IP address from internet for particular domain name?

Answer (score 1):

[DNS](http://www.howtogeek.com/122845/htg-explains-what-is-dns/) is what you're looking for.